# I'm having an issue with casting from GenericIdentity to FormsIdentity on HTML page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an HTML page that is part of my web application that is to be used as a landing page when a user has certified their email address.  The issue is that when I attempt to display the page via the following link: https://devweb.auditedmedia.com/MICenter/EmailCertification/EmailCertify?userName=kathryn@auditedmedia.com&memberNumber=1111475&certSentDate=636966249392940630
I get an error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity' to type 'System.Web.Security.FormsIdentity'.
The link calls the EmailCertify action in the controller EmailCertifiction.

What I'm not understanding is that this landing page has (to my understanding) nothing that would need authentication on it and that's why I don't understand why I'm getting the error message.

When I run the website locally (via my debugger) and then closed it but kept the debugger up and running and click on the link it will work.

Here is a copy of my controller EmailCertification which contains the EmailCertify action as well as a few other functions

```cs
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EmailCertify(string userName, string memberNumber, string certSentDate)
        {
            DateTime certSentDT;

            long lngCertSent = long.Parse(certSentDate);

            certSentDT = new DateTime(lngCertSent);

            if (certSentDT < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14))
                return Redirect("CertificationLinkExpired");

            if(EmailCertification.UpdateDBEmailCertified(userName, int.Parse(memberNumber), certSentDT)) return RedirectToAction("CertifyEmail");

            return RedirectToAction("CertifyEmailFailed");
        }

        public ActionResult CertifyEmail() => View();

        public ActionResult CertificationLinkExpired() => View();

        public ActionResult CertifyEmailFailed() => View();

        [System.Web.Http.Authorize]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EmailCertificationSent(EmailCertifiedModel certModel) => PartialView("_EmailCertificationSent", certModel);
```

The following is my cshtml file that is redirected via the CertifyEmail() call

```html
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Email Certified</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Thank you for certifying your email address.  <a href="https://abcas3.auditedmedia.com/MICenter/MICenter">Click here</a> to go to <a href="https://abcas3.auditedmedia.com/MICenter/MICenter">MIC login</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to have happen is that the HTML file is displayed.  Is there a way to do this or am I not even on the correct path?

Comment: Can you show the entire controller? Have you tried the [AllowAnnonymous] attribute?

Comment: That pretty much was the full controller.  Here it is with the beginning and ending context
```csharp

Comment: Sorry, the controller is as you see above with the following at the 1st few lines
```c#
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ABC.Models;

namespace ABC.Controllers
{
    public class EmailCertificationController : Controller
    {
```

Comment: Also, would I put AllowAnnonymous on my CertifyEmail action?

Comment: Putting AllowAnonymous didn't work